# List in ViewData MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, viewdata

I have the following in the controller:

```
List <string> strResult = new List ();
```

And as will running the class will adding some information

```
strResult.Add ("The Text"); 
strResult.Add ("Text B"); 
strResult.Add ("Text C"); 

return View ("Index", ViewData ["result"] = new SelectList (strResult))
```

And the View

```
<textarea rows="10"> class="form-control" 
@ViewData["resultImport"] 
</ textarea>
```

But the only thing that appears is:

```
System.Web.Mvc.SelectList
```

in textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to load a SelectList into a textarea?   If you would like to return a "string list" you will need to convert your strResults variable from a List to a string in your Controller.  Here is the code to do this:

```
string strReturnString = string.Join(",", strResult.ToArray()); 

ViewData ["result"] = strReturnString;
return View ("Index");
```

Then:

Use `@ViewData["result"]` in your View

Comment: And how do I see a message under the other

Comment: I dont understand your question...are you asking how do you see it in the textarea?  If that is the question than you would do it like this <textarea rows="10" class="form-control">@ViewData["result"]</textarea>